# Pyintaller executable print out unwanted stuff like SpeechRecognition JSON

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, speech-recognition

I use Pyinstaller to create executable. In my program I use SpeechRecognition after I ran the program it prints out a JSON file (from API response) which normally my program not print anything.

for example it print out this one that don't want it to

`result2: {   'alternative': [   {'confidence': 0.97219545, 'transcript': 'hello world'}, {'transcript': 'helloworld'}], 'final': True}`

btw I use`pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`  to make exe file. I didnt use `--windowed` because when I tried it not found  sys.stdout module

Tried to find something in SpeechRecognition module and found out the result2 JSON may come from this.

Comment: I don't want the program to print out result2 JSON

Comment: create an [mre]

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with `speech_recognition`. It's the `recognize_google` function that is printing that `"result2"`. If you're storing the result in a variable, the result is fine (as in, it only contains the words you want, not the rest).

You can fix this by downgrading to speech_recognition 3.8.1. That's the only answer I found so far.